# 1:1 relationships in Laravel returns Undefined property

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I keep getting this error in Laravel 5 when working on a 1:1 database relationship:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$owner
```

In my controller i have method "stuff". When i return $stuff i get:

```
[{"id":4,"demoId":2,"slug":"loremipsum","languageId":1,"countryId":1,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
```

The relationship is on "demoId".

In my model i have this:

```
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Demotable2');
}
```

I'm using this code, that gives an error:

```
$routine = $stuff->owner->get()->toArray();
```

I expect to get the info in the demotable2.  What do i do wrong?

Comment: as @smartrahat said, you should put the `owner` method in your model, not in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain rules that you need to apply when you try to make most of eloquent (`convention over configuration`), the problem you have is in naming your `foreign key`'s, when you use :

```
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Demotable2');
}
```

eloquent expects to find a `foreign key` `demo_id` instead of `demoId`, when you change the name of the foreign key, you need to specify it in the relationship like so :

```
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Demotable2', 'demoId', 'id');
}
```

you read more here : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Especially mentioning the conversion/configuration part helped. I did change all the table names. It works now.

Comment: Yes it's a good practice, convention over configuration, less code writing and more power

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will be in your model.

```
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Demotable2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is defined in your model, not controller.

In `App\Stuff.php`

```
public function owner() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Demotable2::class);
}
```

When this relationship is run, it will automatically look for a `owner_id` on your `stuff` table. However, you are using `demoId`. For that to work you have to define the foreign key in your relationship

```
public function owner() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Demotable2::class, 'demoId');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, since your answer was the same as teeyo i had to choose, theeyo added a link to a resource and mentioned the convention over configuration part. Tha's why i accepted his answer, but yours was actually helping as well.